# Dialogflow v2 Nodejs Client Library UpdateIntent when adding Training Phrases

Tags: node.js, google-api, dialogflow-es

I am trying to use the `updateIntent` function that is part of the Dialogflow v2 Client library for Node.js . The reason I am trying to use it, is to be able to add training phrases to an intent.

I cannot seem to get passed this one. Here is the code I am using for it!:

My GetIntent Function:

```
async function getIntent(intentId) {
  try {
    let responses = await intentsClient.getIntent({name: intentId, intentView: 'INTENT_VIEW_FULL'})
    const response = responses[0]
          // console.log(response)

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      resolve(response)
    })
  } catch (err) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      reject(err)
    })
  }
}
```

My UpdateIntent Function:

```
async function updateIntent(intent) {
  const request = {
    intent: intent,
    languageCode: 'en-US',
    updateMask: {
       paths: ['trainingPhrases']
    },
    intentView: 'INTENT_VIEW_FULL'
  }
  try {
    let responses = await intentsClient.updateIntent(request)
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      resolve(response)
    })
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err)
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      reject(err)
    })
  } 
}
```

The Function that Calls it:

```
async function testUpdateTraining () {
  try {
    let intent = await getIntent('projects/small-talk-1-406ae/agent/intents/ac7f0b68-de5c-4b6f-9393-358dd2b0c1bd')

    let trainingPhrase = { parts: [{ text: 'How should I behave on the trails?'}],
      type: 'EXAMPLE'}
    intent.trainingPhrases.push(trainingPhrase)
    try {
      let updatedIntent = await updateIntent(intent)
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e)
      console.log('failed to update the intent')
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('failed to get intent')
  }
}
```

Now the weird thing is - I am getting a 200 response from the client library call.  The Api doc states that upon a successful response you will get an intent object.  I am getting an intent object with the training phrases inside...

```
    [![{ inputContextNames: \[\],
  events: \[\],
  trainingPhrases:
   \[ { parts: \[Array\],
       name: 'ad0d1f6a-78cf-4e0b-84ca-ec62a45c75dc',
       type: 'EXAMPLE',
       timesAddedCount: 0 },
     { parts: \[Array\],
       name: 'e33cce4b-96ee-4e35-a151-5b09ff603817',
       type: 'EXAMPLE',
       timesAddedCount: 0 },
     { parts: \[Array\],
       name: '7d9b7c56-5fa8-4791-986f-e57b9f90d431',
       type: 'EXAMPLE',
       timesAddedCount: 0 } \],
  outputContexts: \[\],
  parameters: \[\],
  messages:
   \[ { platform: 'PLATFORM_UNSPECIFIED',
       text: \[Object\],
       message: 'text' } \],
  defaultResponsePlatforms: \[\],
  followupIntentInfo: \[\],
  name: 'projects/small-talk-1-406ae/agent/intents/ac7f0b68-de5c-4b6f-9393-358dd2b0c1bd',
  displayName: 'faq.offroad.card1answer',
  priority: 500000,
  isFallback: false,
  webhookState: 'WEBHOOK_STATE_UNSPECIFIED',
  action: 'faq.offroad.card1answer',
  resetContexts: false,
  rootFollowupIntentName: '',
  parentFollowupIntentName: '',
  mlDisabled: true }][1]][1]
```

This is what dialogflow has.  Only two training phrases here, the one I added programmatically does not show up.
[image]
So my question is, how can I format the request so I can update the training phrases without a problem? Is there an example I can run off?

Comment: Hey buddy. You got any solution for this?

Comment: Try removing "updateMask" (comment it out) and it worked for me.

Comment: @AkshayL no not yet!

Comment: I have done that to no avail :(

Comment: I got it working

Comment: @AkshayL thats it? just updateMask?

Comment: Can you share the getIntent function?

Comment: @AkshayL gonna edit the question

Comment: did it work??? Are you trying to add in Small talk?

Comment: It worked! Its weird because I thought I had tried that variant but I guess not!

Comment: this libraray might help in getting list of intent in easy way, https://www.npmjs.com/package/dialogflow-helper I wrote this library on the top of dialogflow rest client

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After trying out a lot, understood that my code worked because i removed update mask. And the languageCode as well, because it was giving me an error.
The code is as below and works fine.
Check it up.

This is the getIntent function:

```
    async function getIntent(intentId) {
    try {
        let responses = await intentsClient.getIntent({
            name: intentId,
            intentView: 'INTENT_VIEW_FULL'
        })
        const response = responses[0];
        console.log(util.inspect(response, false, null, true /* enable colors */ ));

        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            resolve(response)
        })
    } catch (err) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            reject(err)
        })
    }
}
```

The function that calls it:

```
async function testUpdateTraining () {
    try {
        let intent = await getIntent('<your_ID>')

        let trainingPhrase = {
            parts: [{
                text: 'let me call you?'
            }],
            type: 'EXAMPLE'
        }
        intent.trainingPhrases.push(trainingPhrase)
        try {
            let updatedIntent = await updateIntent(intent)
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e)
            console.log('failed to update the intent')
        }
    } catch (err) {
        console.log('failed to get intent')
    }
 }
```

The UpdateIntent function:

```
 async function updateIntent(intent) {
    const request = {
        intent: intent,
        intentView: 'INTENT_VIEW_FULL'
    }
    try {
        let responses = await intentsClient.updateIntent(request)
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            resolve(responses)
        })
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            reject(err)
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: i need the language code since i have to manage 4 languages

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
updateMask: {
       paths: ['training_phrases']
}
```

since paths naming convetion is "snake"